# POST HttpRequest doesn't send any data

Tags: networking, godot, gdscript

I've some trouble for sending a post request to my nodejs server.

I can receive data from the server with GET method, but when I try to send data with POST, I've an empty bracket on return on this function:

```
func _on_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var json = JSON.parse(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    print(json.result)
    print(response_code)
```

And empty bracket on my JSON console.log on the server too.

My code:

```
extends CanvasLayer

func _ready():
    $HTTPRequest.connect("request_completed", self, "_on_request_completed")

func _on_Button_pressed():
    var data = {"name": "Godette"}
    _make_post_request("http://localhost:8080/", data, false)

func _on_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var json = JSON.parse(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    print(json.result)
    print(response_code)

func _on_HTTPRequest_request_completed():
    pass

func _make_post_request(url, data_to_send, use_ssl):
    # Convert data to json string:
    var query = JSON.print(data_to_send)
    # Add 'Content-Type' header:
    var headers = ["Content-Type: application/json"]
    $HTTPRequest.request(url, headers, false, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, query)
```

And this code return this in my console:

```
{}
200
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What is your server supposed to return?

Comment: Quick sanity check... Your server isn't expecting a [CSRF token](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-csrf-tokens-in-express-f867c9e95af0) or other seurity measures with POSTs is it?

Comment: Thanks for replies! My server is a basic node server, who console log the JSON received. But on my Godot script the function _on_request_completed must be print the sent json object on the console . But the json object seems  empty... for my local test, the server has no security.

Comment: `JSON.parse` returns a `JSONParseResult` so is `json_result.error == OK`?

Comment: Can you show your nodejs code? I'm sure the problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

I find nothing wrong with your code. I suppose the wrong code might be your server code. My GDScript code as you can see is similar to yours:

```
extends Control

func _ready():
    $HTTPRequest.connect("request_completed", self, "_on_request_completed")

func _on_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var json = JSON.parse(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    print(json.result)

func _make_post_request(url, data_to_send, use_ssl):
    var query = JSON.print(data_to_send)
    var headers = ["Content-Type: application/json"]
    $HTTPRequest.request(url, headers, use_ssl, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, query)

func _on_Send_pressed():
    _make_post_request("http://127.0.0.1:3200/hello/",
        {"name":"godot"}, false)
```

My server code looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3200;

// middleware

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/hello', (req, res) => {
  const resp = req.body;

  console.log(resp.name);

  res.status(200).json({
     name: resp.name,
     message: 'hello stranger',
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`running at port ${port}`);
});
```

And when I click on the `Send` Button I get this output:
`{message:hello stranger, name:godot}`

Comment: Thanks Timothy, I don’t know why but this code run fine!

Comment: Glad it worked. Without seeing your server side code there isn't much I can say. I can only speculate that the problem might be in your `app.post(...)`. While answering I used [this blog post on alligator](https://alligator.io/nodejs/building-rest-api/) as reference, hope it helps.